# Why only one javascript in the body works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two javascripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cexpiryyear li").on('click',function () {
        var selectedOption1 = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $("#expiry_year").val(selectedOption1);
        alert( $("#2ndexpiry_year").val());
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cexpirymonth li").on('click',function () {
        var selectedOption = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $("#expiry_month").val(selectedOption);
        alert( $("#expiry_month").val());
    });
</script>
```

They are place before the `</body>`. But only the script which is in the last works and the first one wont work.Any solution for this. Why does it happen?

The html is given below

```
 <div class="clearfix">                
                <div class="inline pull-left m-r">


                  <div id="mySelect" class="select btn-group m-b" data-resize="auto">
                    <button style="font-weight:700;background-color:#fff;border-style:solid;
border-width:2px" type="button" id="expirymonth" name="expirymonth" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-white btn-sm dropdown-toggle">
                      <span class="dropdown-label"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
              <input type="hidden" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month"/>
                    <ul id="cexpirymonth" class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li data-value="00" data-selected="true" ><a href="#">Select Month</a></li>
                      <li data-value="01"  class="selectOption"  ><a href="#">01</a></li>
                      <li data-value="02" ><a href="#">02</a></li>
             <li data-value="03" ><a href="#">03</a></li>
                      <li data-value="04" ><a href="#">04</a></li>
             <li data-value="05" ><a  href="#">05</a></li>
                      <li data-value="06" ><a  href="#">06</a></li>
             <li data-value="07" ><a  href="#">07</a></li>
                      <li data-value="08" ><a  href="#">08</a></li>
             <li data-value="09" ><a  href="#">09</a></li>
                      <li data-value="10" ><a  href="#">10</a></li>
             <li data-value="11" ><a href="#">11</a></li>
                      <li data-value="12" ><a href="#">12</a></li>


                    </ul>
                  </div>
</div>
<div class="inline pull-left m-r">

                  <div id="mySelect" class="select btn-group m-b" data-resize="auto">
                    <button style="background-color:#fff;font-weight:700;border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;" type="button" id="expiryyear" name="expiryyear" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-white btn-sm dropdown-toggle">
                      <span class="dropdown-label"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
            <input type="hidden" id="expiry_year" name="expiry_year"/>
                    <ul id="cexpiryyear" class="dropdown-menu">
<li data-value="2011" data-selected="true"><a href="#">Select Year</a></li>
<li data-value="2012"><a href="#">2012</a></li>
<li data-value="2013"><a href="#">2013</a></li>
<li data-value="2014"><a href="#">2014</a></li>
<li data-value="2015"><a href="#">2015</a></li>
<li data-value="2016"><a href="#">2016</a></li>
<li data-value="2017"><a href="#">2017</a></li>
<li data-value="2018"><a href="#">2018</a></li>
<li data-value="2019"><a href="#">2019</a></li>
<li data-value="2020"><a href="#">2020</a></li>
<li data-value="2021"><a href="#">2021</a></li>
<li data-value="2022"><a href="#">2022</a></li>
<li data-value="2023"><a href="#">2023</a></li>
<li data-value="2024"><a href="#">2024</a></li>
<li data-value="2025"><a href="#">2025</a></li>
<li data-value="2026"><a href="#">2026</a></li>
<li data-value="2027"><a href="#">2027</a></li>
<li data-value="2028"><a href="#">2028</a></li>
<li data-value="2029"><a href="#">2029</a></li>
<li data-value="2030"><a href="#">2030</a></li>
<li data-value="2031"><a href="#">2031</a></li>
<li data-value="2032"><a href="#">2032</a></li>
<li data-value="2033"><a href="#">2033</a></li>
<li data-value="2034"><a href="#">2034</a></li>
<li data-value="2035"><a href="#">2035</a></li>
<li data-value="2036"><a href="#">2036</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </div>

</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Only the last javascript works,and not the one above it.I tried plaing them in a single tag,but not working

Comment: Why not put them in one script tag?

Comment: Can we see the markup?

Comment: _What exactly_ doesn't work? Did you check the Console for errors?

Comment: When binding both the script in one tag,none of the scripts works

Comment: You do realize there is no element with the ID `2ndexpiry_year` in the posted HTML ?

Comment: I removed that and updated the code

Comment: So what, is it working now?! SO is not a debugging plateform, i mean don't modify code in question until it works. Ask an appropriate question

Comment: Nope its not working!!..ONly the script which is placed last works.I tried interchanging.One of the scripts which isplaced last works well..The other above it wont work

Comment: Seems to work fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/4KRhq/

Comment: No @adeno,u have given the wrong id,id is not expiryyear,its for another element ,its expiry_year

Comment: That doesn't matter, as long the element exists, and has a value property, it works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/4KRhq/1/

Answer (score 1):

id's can't start with a number - the script is actually running, but `2ndexpiry_year` is an invalid id.

Comment: IDs *can* start with a number [HTML5 ID Rules](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id)

Comment: Holy crap, you got upvoted on that? In HTML5 the spec says "must contain a character and no spaces", and that's it, nothing about not starting with numbers.

Comment: Not true in `HTML5`, see http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class for example

Comment: Let's face it, a lot of browsers are still in use that don't support HTML5, and it's almost certainly the issue here. Plus it's a good idea to be as backward-compatible as possible.

Comment: @DimeCadmium That as well! Furthermore, I'd never personally really use an Number to describe an element within my HTML, unless it's an auto generated element by using JavaScript `Date()` object for example - but the fact is, it *doesn't* answer the question.

Comment: I have changes the id..but the real prob is,one of the scripts doesnt work.Only the one which is paced last works..

Comment: you didn't change both id's @user3105409 -- it works here, shows an alert

Comment: (Oh and to @adeneo if you're going off the spec as to whether or not something works, you're really doing it quite wrong. How many browsers 100% follow the HTML5 spec at current? ;) )

Comment: @DimeCadmium "id's can't start " is wrong, should be "id's shouldn't start" because CSS still doesn't support it. Anyway, this was not OP's issue.

Comment: That's not the point, the point is that your answer is wrong. The statement "can't start with a number" is plain wrong, as an ID *can* start with a number in all modern browsers, and even in older browsers it should work with getElementById even if it's not according to spec.

Comment: "even in older browsers it should work with getElementById" untrue. I've had the problem before. "CSS still doesn't support it." untrue. backslash escaping works in CSS. (and I think it would anyway) "this was not OP's issue" true. was unknown until after OP edited.

Comment: @DimeCadmium you know, you can have multiple elements with same ID and still make it works, is it a reason to use it? What is the point of your previous comment? I don't get it. I should have said CSS still doesn't support natively IDs starting with number. But now i realize this is a non sense conversation because primaly you said; "Ids can't start with number". Well, now i should approve it in some way

Comment: You **shouldn't** (and often **can't** due to browser differences) use ID's starting with a number, even though officially (by spec) you "can" was my point @A.Wolff :)

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the fact that there is no reason for you to put everything in several tags, you should only bind event when the page is loaded.

Thus:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cexpiryyear li").on('click',function () {
         var selectedOption1 = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $("#2ndexpiry_year").val(selectedOption1);
        alert( $("#2ndexpiry_year").val());
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really apply when it's immediately before the </body> (it's still a good idea, but it's not required).

Comment: I'm just clarifying, not disagreeing :)

Comment: @DimeCadmium to close this conversation, I didn't say that it wouldn't work without the ready call, so there is no reason to say "This doesn't apply". It *does* apply. You *should* put that kind of code on an onload event, even right before `</body>`. You never know how code might be moved in the future (or appended after the script markup).

Comment: @ArlaudPierre you made an *answer* (as compared to a *comment*). That implies it is an answer to the question, which was "why doesn't this work".

Comment: _"You should put that kind of code on an onload event, even right before </body>. You never know how code might be moved in the future"_ What? No. Coding defensively is all very well, but what you suggest is overkill. Any intermediate JS coder would know better than to move such code indiscriminately. In any case there's no reason at all to think that this would solve the problem the OP is having.